# USB-C to HDMI/VGA DisplayPort doesn't extend display

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, displayport

I just bought a USB-C to HDMI and VGA adapter. [This one](https://www.dlink.com/en/products/dub-v210-usb-c-to-hdmivga-adapter)

But I have surprised that the HDMI and VGA are detected as only one screen, the HDMI and VGA are mirrored, So I cannot use my laptop with 3 independent displays.

Is there any solution for this in mac or windows?

And thanks.

Comment: You'll need another for a third screen. The advert is very cleverly worded to make you think it might, but it doesn't support 2 independent screens, only mirroring.

Comment: I agree with Tetsujin that this adapter does not appear to support two independent displays.  Also Apple is (in)famous for not supporting two displays on a single USB-C port so even if you had an adapter that supported two independent displays then it's not going to work on macOS.  Windows, even when running on Apple hardware, will support two independent displays on one USB-C port if the hardware in the computer supports it.  This limit does not apply to adapters with its own GPU, like DisplayLink, which is a whole different issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, those adapters will only support mirroring.  You would likely need USB-C to DisplayPort 1.2 if you want to extend your displays via daisy chaining.